# How to use alignat format

Tags: alignat

I have this code:

```
\begin{alignat*}
    && u=\tan^{-1}{x} &&v=x\\
    && du=\frac{1}{1+x^2} &&dv=1
\end{alignat*}
```

And I am trying to align the u with du and v with dv. I get errors and the overleaf produces this: [image]
What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I have the following errors:
[image]
Line 21: missing number, treated as zero
Line 23: amsmath error: extra & on this line
Line 23: Misplaced \omit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must tell `alignat` how many “right-left” pairs of columns you want. And you have to provide the desired separation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
& u=\arctan{x}       &\qquad& v=x\\
& du=\frac{1}{1+x^2} &&       dv=1
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I used “arctan” because I believe the symbol you use is mathematically wrong, so I cannot use it.

If you want to align at the `=` signs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
 u&=\arctan{x}      &\qquad  v&=x\\
du&=\frac{1}{1+x^2} &       dv&=1
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Kai This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 6):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

- please always provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document, which we can compile as it is and which reproduce your problem
- environment `alignat` requires data on how many columns you like to have (since you did not define them, you receive errors)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{3}
     u & = \tan^{-1}{x}     &\qquad &  v & = x\\
    du & = \frac{1}{1+x^2}  &       & dv & = 1
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you like to have a bigger distance between columns with math expression, rather use `align` than `alignat` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
     u & = \tan^{-1}{x}      &  v & = x\\
    du & = \frac{1}{1+x^2}   & dv & = 1
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What does \qquad do?

Comment: @KaiML, it is simple to see :-). Remove it in observe difference in compiled result! It define distance between the first and last column.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!

Comment: @CarLaTeX, thank you very much for editing my answer!

Comment: @Zarko You're welcome!